# Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string. Using value from CSV in TOC

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, datatool, csv

I am using `datatool` to read `csv` file and get values from it. I also want to use these values in a chapter names. I have no problems with `TOC` and pages. I can see values from my csv file. But `bookmarks` create by `hyperref` (I think) have only `PK`/indexes, but not values from csv file.

Additionally I have got this warning: `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string.`

My values in csv file have only A-Za-z0-9 letters and not special Unicode symbols like `\sqrt`.

Here is my sample code that can show the issue.

```
%&xelatex
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{noto-mono} % to support hyperref package
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\usepackage{datatool}

\author{Some}
\title{Any}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
PK,Value
1,Val1
2,Val2
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{values}{data.csv}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\getValue}{m}{\DTLfetch{values}{PK}{#1}{Value}}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\chapter{AAA \getValue{1}}
\chapter{BBB \getValue{2}}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

your \getValue command is not expandable, and \DTLfetch is not expandable either (most datatools command aren't). You need to store your data in a way that they can be retrieved in an expandable way.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\usepackage{datatool}

\author{Some}
\title{Any}

\begin{filecontents*}[force]{data.csv}
PK,Value
1,Val1
2,Val2
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{values}{data.csv}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N\g_sergei_data_prop 
\NewDocumentCommand{\storeValue}{mm}{\prop_gput:NVV\g_sergei_data_prop#1#2}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getValue}{m}{\prop_item:Nn\g_sergei_data_prop{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DTLforeach{values}{\mynum=PK,\myval=Value}{\storeValue\mynum\myval}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\chapter{AAA \getValue{1}}
\chapter{BBB \getValue{2}}


\end{document}
```

(If a prop is the right data container depends on your actual use case)

Comment: Thanks. It works. No warnings and bookmarks in PDF have correct values.

Comment: @Nicola Talbot It would be nice to add new or update existing methods in `datatool` package to make compatible with `hyperref` package based on Ulrike Fischer recommendation.

Comment: @SergeiZinovyev Nicola will not see your ping. If you want to make a feature request for datatool go to her website.

Comment: Yes, I reported it on her website. Additionally Overleaf has some parsing issue with your code. Overleaf reports: Your code has errors that need to be fixed before the auto-compile can run. It compiles and generates valid and correct PDF file with correct bookmarks, but auto-compile feature is really OFF. I also reported it to them.

Comment: Overleaf suggests using `%%begin novalidate  LaTeX3_commands %%end novalidate` as a workaround. See: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check#Disabling_Code_Check_globally